# Animation bending problem when exporting from blender to UE5

Tags: animation, mesh, unreal-engine

I animated a simple blob using an armature using very basic rotations and scaling. It looks fine in blender but when I export it to ue5 the mesh bends inwards breaking completely the animation. I add 2 pictures of the key frames of the animation in blender as intended and then a picture of how the right side vertices of the mesh move inwards in the animation exported to ue5. I also add a picture with the settings used when exporting. I want to add that I tried baking the animations in blender before exporting to see the result in case something broke in the process but after baking it keeps looking the same in blender.

My best guess is it might have something to do with the vertex bone weight distribution in UE5 somehow being different to blender and/or the interpolation between frames having issues with rotation but I am a complete newbie to making and exporting animations so it's more of a wild guess than anything else.

Edit: The reason I think it has to do with rotation problems is that when going frame by frame on the affected area, it shows that the vertices around the top right area close to the top right bone start rotating to one side until completely inverting and going inside the mesh as shown in the added image.

Edit2: It seems like the bone hierarchy has some transform issues when exporting/importing because the deformation only happens when both parent bones and their children are rotated together. It also looks like the problem only occurs in the interpolation between frames while the frames defined in blender are represented correctly.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]